# Switch & Combination DAX/Power BI

Tags: excel, function, powerbi, dax

I am trying to build a switch statement where -

`Table1'[Column A]` value need to be exact value for `Table1'[Column B]`, so if on both of the row have the yes value the output should be "Table1Yes".

On the Second condition -
if `'Table1'[Column A]` & Table2'[Column A] both have Yes value than the output should be "Table2Yes" else the output should be empty.

This is my query-

```
Both = SWITCH(TRUE();
'Table1'[Column A] & Table1'[Column B]= "Yes"; "Table1Yes";
'Table1'[Column A] = "Yes" & Table2'[Column A]= "Yes";"Table2Yes";"Empty")
```

But it seems like the `&` function is not working in the Switch statement, also I am unable to call the Table2'[Column A] from Table 1 although both of the tables are connect to each other.

Anyone knows any solution !!

Comment: There's an AND() function that might work instead of the &

Comment: @BarneyL Could you kindly give an example!

Comment: Details here - https://dax.guide/and/

Comment: `&` is string concatenation. `&&` is logical AND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DAX it would be:

```
Both = SWITCH(TRUE();
              AND('Table1'[Column A] = "Yes"; 
                  'Table1'[Column B] = "Yes"); 
              "Table1Yes";
              AND('Table1'[Column A] = "Yes"; 
                  'Table2'[Column A] = "Yes");
              "Table2Yes";
              "Empty")
```